# User defined parameter within code block of ArcMap field calculator in model gives ERROR 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, python-parser, error-999999

I am using Reclass within a Code Block in Field Calculator in a Model to calculate field values for a variable based on several other fields.

Using reclass is much quicker than select and then using Calculate Field.

The example below works fine.

[image]

This is a simple example of the way i am using this. The typical use references many more fields.

My question is this.

Instead of a hard coded and fixed value i wish to use a user generated Parameter.Therefore I set a new variable named "Buildx", set this as a Parameter. Then i replaced the value of "30" in the code block with %Buildx%. This should work as in line variable substitution, however i get the 99999 error code.

[image]

I tried setting the standalone variable Parameter as either Any Value or as a Long Integer, but neither worked.

Error message below - the standalone variable has been coded as 30, so it appears as 30 in the error message, but results in an error.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Python code but your Expression Type in the second screenshot is VB ;)